# OpenCV Image Alignment gone wrong

Tags: python, opencv, alignment, orb

I want to align this image

[image]

so that i looks like this:

[image]

To do so, I use openCV to identify the keypoints in both images. After that, the matching keypoints are brought together and with the warpPerspective-function of openCV I want to align the rotated one, properly. At the end, both images should look like the same.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os

original_img = r"C:\car.png"
rotated_img = r"C:\car_rotated.png"

# Read imgs:
img_original = cv2.imread(original_img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_original = cv2.cvtColor(img_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_rotated = cv2.imread(rotated_img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_rotated = cv2.cvtColor(img_rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# convert to grayscale:
img_original_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_rotated_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# Identify KeyPoints:
MAX_NUM_FEATURES = 500
orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_NUM_FEATURES)

keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_original_gray, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img_rotated_gray, None)

# Create a Brute Force Matcher object.
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck = True)

matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DescriptorMatcher_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

# Matches sort:
#matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

# The matches with shorter distance are the ones we want.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x : x.distance)

# Remove not so good matches
numGoodMatches = int(len(matches)*0.1)
matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]


# Perform Homographie
points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.queryIdx].pt
    
# Homographie
h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points2, points1, cv2.RANSAC)

height, width, channels = img_original.shape
im2_reg = cv2.warpPerspective(img_rotated, h, (width, height))
```

The output is the following:

[image]

Why the strange output?

Comment: debug the problem. know the values of your variables (number of keypoints). the [mre] article contains a link to 
a "how to debug..." article. -- look at `opencv/samples/python/find_obj.py`

Comment: I tried that of course. Not just that I used different paramters for the features, I found out that it could help to use David Lowe’s ratio-test in order to get the best matches. In addition to that I tried SIFT, with no improvement.